# Error parsing VALID Json file in Java

Tags: java, json

I have a JSON file:

```
{
  "dev_status": "test",
  "test": {
    "id": "0",
    "access_key": "xxx",
    "image_directory": "D:/test_folder/"
  },
  "release": {
    "id": "1",
    "access_key": "xxx",
    "image_directory": "/home/imgs/"
  }
}
```

and I'm trying to turn into `org.json.JSONObject` with the following code:

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    URL configURL = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(configPath);
    if (configURL == null) {
        try {
            throw new IOException("Config file with such name wasn't found.");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        JSONObject config = new JSONObject(configURL.getFile());
}
```

But I'm getting exception:

```
org.json.JSONException: A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at 1 [character 2 line 1]
```

So I obviously have a valid JSON object starting with '{' but I still get this error. How do I fix it?

Comment: the JSON is not correct

Comment: use array notation for two object [{...}, {...}]

Comment: @Harry It is. I checked it with JSONLint

Comment: JSONObject takes the JSON as String, not a filename containing the JSON.

Comment: @FlorianFray oh, ok, thanks, I should have understood it reading other stackoverflow topics about this error.

Comment: No, you should use [Javadoc](http://static.javadoc.io/org.json/json/20160810/org/json/JSONObject.html) to know what is expected as argument in constructors/methods:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used your json in test.json file and used the below snippet

```
    String myJson = null;
    try {
            myJson = new Scanner(new File("test.json")).useDelimiter("\\Z")
                        .next();

            JSONObject myJsonobject = new JSONObject(myJson);

            System.out.println(myJsonobject.get("dev_status"));
            System.out.println(myJsonobject.get("test"));
        } 
   catch (ParseException e) 
      {
           e.printStackTrace();
      } 
   catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
     {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
```

And the output was

```
test
{"image_directory":"D:\/test_folder\/","access_key":"xxx","id":"0"}
```

Comment: I was about to post an answer on my own question. Well, thanks, anyway

Answer (score 0):

For reference, another way:

```
public class JSONTest {

    private JSONObject getConfig(String configPath) {
        Path path = new File(configPath).toPath();
        try {
            String jsonString = new String(Files.readAllBytes(path), Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
            return new JSONObject(jsonString);
        } catch (IOException | JSONException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Couldn't process JSON file: " + configPath);
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testJson() throws JSONException {
        JSONObject config = getConfig("foo.json");
        assertThat(config.getString("dev_status"), is("test"));
        assertThat(config.getJSONObject("release").getString("access_key"), is("xxx"));
    }
}
```

As notes, this:

- extracts core functionality to a method
- handles the exceptions better
- uses UTF-8 explicitly (nearly always the correct case for JSON)
- adds basic JUnit & Hamcrest unit tests

Hope that helps someone.